# OrientDB batch commands on unique edges and vertices

Tags: orientdb

Suppose I want to create a set of unique edges and vertices.

```
create vertex A set etc.

create vertex B set etc.

create edge AB, create edge AC,
```

And all of these edges and vertices are unique--so some of the commands will likely fail when they are unique.

How do I batch these commands such that I am guaranteed all commands will be run, even when some commands fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your case, I have a Vertex class with a name property (unique index), you can execute batch commands in different ways:

- **Studio**

  ```
  begin
  LET a = create vertex User set name = 'John'
  LET b = create vertex User set name = 'Jane'
  LET c = create edge FriendOf from $a to $b
  commit retry 100
  return $c
  ```
- **Java API**

  ```
  OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph(currentPath);
  String cmd = "begin\n";
  cmd += "let $user2 = UPDATE User SET user_id = 'userX' UPSERT RETURN AFTER @rid WHERE user_id = 'userX'\n";
  cmd += "let $service = UPDATE Service SET service = 'serviceX' UPSERT RETURN AFTER @rid WHERE service = 'serviceX'\n";
  cmd += "CREATE edge link FROM $user2 TO $service\n";
  cmd += "commit";
  g.command(new OCommandScript("sql", cmd)).execute();
  ```
- **Console**

  create a .txt file with your code like this:

  ```
  connect remote:localhost/stack49801389 root root

  begin
  create vertex User set name = 'John'
  create vertex User set name = 'Jane'
  create edge FriendOf from $a to $b
  commit retry 100
  return $c
  ```

  and then run it by console

For more information you can take a look at this [link](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-batch.html)

Hope it helps

Regards